# How do I prevent my UISplitViewController from displaying the master VC when rotating to portrait?

Tags: ios, uikit, autolayout, uisplitviewcontroller, size-classes

I have a `UISplitViewController` that is used to edit some text.

The flow is basically like this:

1. The user creates a new note.
2. The user is transitioned to the Detail View Controller to create or edit said note.
3. User can edit the text in either portrait or landscape.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The problem is, when the user is editing the contents in landscape in the detail view controller and he suddenly rotates the device to portrait, the displayed VC will be the master VC instead of the Detail VC (seen in picture 3). I'd like to stay at the detail VC.

I was looking at Apple's Notes.app and when you rotate the device to portrait when editing a note you will stay at the detail VC instead of going back to Master. So this must definitely be possible.

Is there an specific property I need to modify for this? Sadly I was looking at [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISplitViewController) and I couldn't find anything related.

Comment: I am actually working on a master-detail app right now and the way you describe how you want the project to work is the way it works by default. Did you change something with the default project? Start a new master-detail project... don't change anything, and see if it works the way you expect it to.

Comment: I actually believe I have found my way to fix it on the `splitViewController:secondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController` delegate method. I never touched this method so I'm not entirely sure if it is default. Regardless, I will edit this if needed :)

Comment: Another thing you could look in to is `UISplitViewController`'s property `preferredDisplayMode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is typical of me to solve my issues 5 minutes after asking them on SO.

Turns out the `splitViewController:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController` `UISplitViewController` delegate method is in charge of choosing the "collapse" of the views. What originally threw me off is that I didn't consider going back to portrait as something that would be a "collapse".

So I edited the delegate method with this:

```
func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController:UIViewController!, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController:UIViewController!) -> Bool {
    if let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController {
        if let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? TextEditorViewController {
            if topAsDetailController.inEditMode {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

The text editor view "won't collapse onto the master view" when rotating to portrait now.